# chef-shell insufficient permissions

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I tried to create a directory in chef using this simple block of code

```
...
directory "/opt/myfolder" do
  owner "abc"
  group "abc"
  mode "0755"
  action :create
end
...
```

When i execute this using "chef-client" it works. But when i execute this in chef-shell (running in client mode), I get this error

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'directory[/opt/myfolder/]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::InsufficientPermissions
-----------------------------------------
Cannot create directory[/opt/myfolder/] at /opt/myfolder/ due to insufficient permissions
```

I am using chef-shell to debug my recipes

In chef-shell I am using `node.run_chef` to run start a client run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running chef-shell with `sudo` or as root? If not, you need to.

It would be interesting to know the output of

```
`whoami`
```

when run in chef-shell. That would tell you what user it thinks it is running as. You could add that to the recipe and see what the output is when running as `chef-client`. I'd guess that chef-client is running as root.